# trying to implement the canny edge using opencv on qt creator

Tags: qt, opencv

i am trying to convert a image to canny image using opencv function in qt gui. when i press a gui button to convert the original image to canny the program crashes in release but in debug mode it show an error R6010.

```
void MainWindow::edgeImage()
    {
    IplImage *image1 =cvLoadImage("Desert.jpg");
    IplImage *Gray = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(image1), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
    cvCvtColor(image1, Gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    IplImage *Edge = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(image1), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
    cvCanny( Gray, Edge, 10, 100 );
    ui->label_2->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*IplImage2QImage(Edge))  ;           
    }
```

thank u in advance

Comment: you should not use opencv's deprecated c-api, but the c++ api (cv::Mat) instead.

Comment: tq u berak i got the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a small changes  its perfectly working

```
void MainWindow::edgeImage()
{
image =cvLoadImage(FileName.toLocal8Bit().data());
Gray = cvCreateImage(cvSize(image->width,image->height),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1 );
cvCvtColor(image, Gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
canny= cvCreateImage(cvSize(image->width,image->height),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1 );
cvCanny(Gray,canny,50,150,3);
QImage imgCanny = QImage((const unsigned char*)canny->imageData,canny->width,canny->height,QImage::Format_Indexed8);
imgCanny.setPixel(0,0,qRgb(0,0,0));
ui->label_3->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(imgCanny).scaled(ui->label_3->size()));
}
```